# How can I turn off automatic creation of a local repository for an existing project?

Tags: xcode

I have an existing Xcode (4.3) project which will automatically always create a local git repository (if I delete the repository via Organizer, then close and reopen the project its been recreated).
How can I disable it from doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i'm not wrong you have to re-create the project but this time do not select the create with a local git repository option.